# warning lnk4006 in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

```
I have two classes given following

FIRST CLASS:
=======================================

#ifndef SAPPOSITIONCLASS_HPP
#define SAPPOSITIONCLASS_HPP
#include "SapArchive.hpp"
class SapPositionClass
{
 double md_latitude;
 double md_longitude;
public:
    SapPositionClass(double latitude,double longitude)
    double GetLatitude() const;
    double GetLongitude() const;
    void SetPosition(double latitude,double longitude)
    friend SapArchive& operator <<(SapArchive& stream,const SapPositionClass& obj);
    friend SapArchive& operator >>(SapArchive& stream,SapPositionClass& obj);
    ~SapPositionClass();
};

   SapArchive& operator <<(SapArchive& stream,const SapPositionClass& obj)
   {
    stream << obj.mush_Id << obj.msz_title << obj.md_latitude << obj.md_longitude << obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
   }

   SapArchive& operator >>(SapArchive& stream,SapPositionClass& obj)
   {
    stream >> obj.mush_Id >> obj.msz_title >> obj.md_latitude >> obj.md_longitude >> obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
   }
#endif

SECOND CLASS:
=============================================
#define SAPMINEFIELDBREACHCLASSS_HPP
#include "SapEntityClass.hpp"
#include "SapPositionClass.hpp"
class SapMinefieldBreachClass
{
    unsigned short mush_minefieldId;
    QString msz_breachDescription;
    SapPositionClass mobj_position;
public:
    SapMinefieldBreachClass(unsigned short minefieldId,SapPositionClass position, QString description);
    unsigned short GetMinefieldId() const;
    QString GetBreachDescription() const;
    void SetBreachDescription(const QString breachDescription);
    SapPositionClass GetPosition() const;
    void SetPosition(SapPositionClass position);
};
#endif

SAFE LANE CLASS
---------------------------
#ifndef SAPSAFELANECLASS_HPP
#define SAPSAFELANECLASS_HPP
#include "SapEntityClass.hpp"
#include "SapPositionClass.hpp"
            class SapSafeLaneClass : public SapEntityClass
            {
                unsigned short mush_minefieldId;
                QList<SapPositionClass> mobj_layoutPointList;
                unsigned short mush_widthMeter;
            public:
                SapSafeLaneClass(unsigned short minefieldId,const unsigned short id,const QString title);
                SapSafeLaneClass(unsigned short minefieldId,const unsigned short id,const QString title,unsigned short width,QList<SapPositionClass> layoutPointList)throw (SapArgumentNullException);
                unsigned short GetMinefieldId() const;
                unsigned short GetWidth() const;
                QList<SapPositionClass> GetLayoutPointList() const;
                void SetLayoutPointList(QList<SapPositionClass> layoutPointList) throw (SapArgumentNullException);
};
```

#endif

PROBLEM:
   when i compiling these classes i get following warning

---

SapSafeLaneClass.obj:-1: warning: LNK4006: "class SapArchive & __cdecl operator<<(class 
   SapArchive &,class SapPositionClass const &)" 
   (??6@YAAAVSapArchive@AAV3452@ABVSapPositionClass@012@@Z) already defined in       SapMinefieldBreachClass.obj; 
   second definition ignored

please help to avoid this warning....

Comment: The warning is shown in `SapSafeLaneClass`. Can you edit your post to include the content of that class?

Comment: i have added safe lane class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `inline` keyword to your definitions of `operator <<(SapArchive&,const SapPositionClass&)` and `operator >>(SapArchive&,SapPositionClass&)` in `SapPostionClass.hpp`:

```
inline
SapArchive& operator <<(SapArchive& stream,const SapPositionClass& obj)
{
    stream << obj.mush_Id << obj.msz_title << obj.md_latitude << obj.md_longitude << obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
}

inline
SapArchive& operator >>(SapArchive& stream,SapPositionClass& obj)
{
    stream >> obj.mush_Id >> obj.msz_title >> obj.md_latitude >> obj.md_longitude >> obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
}
```

Being full definitions in the header, each of these functions gets implemented in each object file for every `.cpp` file that they get included in.  That's why the linker complains about the function in one object file being already defined in another object file. This is a violation of C++'s "one definition rule".

The `inline` keyword is used to explicitly permit multiple definitions of a function (as long as they are identical).

As an alternative, you could remove the definition of the functions from the header file, leaving only a prototype for them there.  Then put the definition in a single `.cpp` file for the linker to find:

```
// in SapPositionClass.hpp:

SapArchive& operator <<(SapArchive& stream,const SapPositionClass& obj);
SapArchive& operator >>(SapArchive& stream,SapPositionClass& obj);
```

And:

```
// in SapPositionClass.cpp:

SapArchive& operator <<(SapArchive& stream,const SapPositionClass& obj)
{
    stream << obj.mush_Id << obj.msz_title << obj.md_latitude << obj.md_longitude << obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
}

SapArchive& operator >>(SapArchive& stream,SapPositionClass& obj)
{
    stream >> obj.mush_Id >> obj.msz_title >> obj.md_latitude >> obj.md_longitude >> obj.msh_altitudeMeter;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. Can you explain me why this showing warning before?